# evince document viewer not showing wireless printer

Tags: printing, pdf, 18.10, evince, document

For some reason Evince document viewer is not showing me my wireless printer. Libreoffice and other applications show my printer and prints fine.I'm using Ubuntu 18.10.

Answer (score 1):

I ran the command 
`system-config-printer` from the commandline and added the printer in the UI. After that, the Document Viewer showed the printer alright.